# Changing dates for part of a flight

Tags: air-travel, layovers, cancellations

I'm on vacation right now, and my return flight passes through San Francisco on its way to Seattle where I live.

I just heard about an awesome thing happening in San Francisco the day I get there. I'm willing to buy a whole new plane ticket from SFO to SEA if need be, but even if that's what I need to do, I'd still like to let the airline know I won't be on the flight.

Whats the best way to go about getting a longer layover?

Comment: Changing your existing flight has a good chance of being less expensive than booking a new one. What have you tried? What did they tell you when you called the airline?

Comment: Are you checking bags?

Answer (score 3):

You can amend your ticket by telephone or, for some airlines, online. Usually you will pay a change fee and any difference in fare between the new and old itineraries.

It is worth considering that failing to show up for the first leg may result in the remaining legs being cancelled.

Comment: I think it's the last leg that Forrest wants to skip.

Comment: Attempting to ammend the ticket costs $700 while booking a new ticket costs <$200.

I think this is mostly because the airline doesn't want to (or doesnt have the tools) to book a flight with a layover in LA. They are also obviously unwilling to ammend to a flight with a different airliner.

Answer (score 0):

I called the Airline and they do indeed offer a service to amend your ticket. However, amending my ticket came out to about the same price as booking another direct flight with the same airliner to SEA, which is about 3 times the price of a new ticket with a different airliner.

Soooo, since I am not checking any bags, and the flight I want to reschedule is the last leg of my flight, I think Ill be intentionally missing my flight and booking a new one. It is a shame that the airlines don't appear to have a way for me to let them know they can rebook my seat.

Comment: You may want to see if you can get a partial refund ($$ or credit) for canceling the last leg rather than just skipping it outright.